# Not able to get spread sheet in Google Drive API that is added using Spreadsheet API

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have a project where I will have to add google sheets and then later I will have to update.

I'm able to add the spreadsheet and here is the code I'm using

```
    public string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
    static string ApplicationName = "SheetUpdate";

    public SheetsService AuthorizeGoogleApp()
    {
        string fileName = "./credentials.json";
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream =
            new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = "token.json";
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }
        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });
        return service;
    }


    public string CreateNewSheet(string sheetTitle)
    {
        var newSheet = new Spreadsheet();
        newSheet.Properties = new SpreadsheetProperties();
        newSheet.Properties.Title = sheetTitle;
        var nsheet = AuthorizeGoogleApp().Spreadsheets.Create(newSheet).Execute();
        return nsheet.SpreadsheetId.ToString();
    }
```

However, I need to get the sheet later and for that I will have to compare it by name to add the relevant data.
But I didn't found any solution to get the sheet title by using `SheetsService API`.

I can get it using the `Google Drive API` like

```
    public SpreadsheetsService AuthorizeGoogleDrive()
    {
        string keyFilePath = @"C:\Users\abc\429e5c50bdab.p12";
        string serviceAccountEmail = "xyz@xyz-1546703100663.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        var serviceAccountCredentialInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = new[] { "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds" }
        }.FromCertificate(certificate);

        var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(serviceAccountCredentialInitializer);

        if (!credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Result)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Access token request failed.");

        var requestFactory = new GDataRequestFactory(null);
        requestFactory.CustomHeaders.Add("Authorization: Bearer " + credential.Token.AccessToken);
        var service = new SpreadsheetsService(null) { RequestFactory = requestFactory };
        return service;
    }

    public void GetSheetByTitle(string title)
    {
        var service = AuthorizeGoogleDrive();

        SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.Query(query);

        if (feed.Entries.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are no sheets");
        }

        // Iterate through all of the spreadsheets returned and get id by title
        foreach (SpreadsheetEntry sheet in feed.Entries)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sheet.Title.Text);
            }
        }
  }
```

The issue is, `SheetsService` is using `credentials.json` which contains the credentials for gmail account and sheet gets added there and `SpreadSheetService` can't be connected (or I wasn't able to) using credentials and can only be connected via service account which uses a different email and the sheet will not be available for service email until and unless I manually share it with the service account.

I'm looking for 1 of these 2 solutions:

1 - To get Sheet Title with `SheetsService API`

2 - Connect both API's with the same account (service account or gmail credentials)

**Update**

When I try to use credentials to connect `SpreadSheetService` like

```
    public SpreadsheetsService AuthorizeGoogleDrive2()
    {
        var service = new SpreadsheetsService(null);
        service.setUserCredentials("xyz@gmail.com", "***");
        return service;
    }
```

I get `error execution of authentication request returned unexpected result 404`

Comment: Can you give more information about what you mean by "can't be connected using credentials"? I'd expect it to work fine with user credentials. What happened when you tried?

Comment: @JonSkeet please check the updated question

Comment: That doesn't look like C# code - that looks more like Java (with `setUserCredentials`). Also, I've just noticed the use of `GDataRequestFactory` in your earlier code. Could you clarify exactly which packages you're using, including the versions involved? I'd suggest using the `Google.Apis.Sheets.v4` package.

Comment: @JonSkeet for I'm using using `Google.Apis.Sheets.v4` api. 
And I'm using `GDataRequestFactory` because `SpreadsheetsService` doesn't accept `UserCredential` and `setUserCredentials` isn't working for me.
So the only option left and worked in my case was `RequestFactory`
Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: I'd be really surprised if SpreadsheetsService doesn't accept UserCredential in the normal way, i.e. via the BaseClientService.Initializer. I'm pretty sure I've used that before. What happens when you try that? (I'll try it myself in the meantime.)

Comment: Hang on, I'm just looking again - the `SpreadsheetsService` is where you're using GDataRequest - which library is *that* from? (I'd expect to use Google.Apis.Drive.v3 for Drive things - use the `DriveService`.)

Comment: Its from `Google.GData.Client`. `SpreadsheetsService ` only accepts string in constructor

Comment: That's a very *very* old API (last updated in 2013). I'd strongly suggest not using that any more. It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do with it, but I'd expect you to be able to get everything from the Sheets API directly.

Comment: In particular, what happened when you *tried* to get the title with the Sheets API? If you could just provide a [mcve] showing what you tried to fetch the title, and what the result was, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Ok I will replace it. I need to get all the spreadsheets and loop through them to match the Title and then get sheet id to work on it. I'm not able to get Title with Sheets API

Comment: ok I need to get the sheet title but I'm not able to locate any API request in Sheet API https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/

Comment: so was not able to try anything with Sheet API for that purpose

Comment: You can fetch a sheet once you know the ID (using `service.Spreadsheets.Get(...)` and I'd expect that to return the title. To list the documents, you'd use the Drive API - as I said before, I'd suggest using Google.Apis.Drive.v3. I don't know if there's a way of getting the titles *while* listing files though.

Comment: Looking at the Drive API (via "Try this" in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) you can use a `q` value of `mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'` to only find spreadsheets. The Name property in each file looks like it's the title, so that should work fine for you.

Comment: I create a sheet and then use it later maybe few days later. Yes I can save ID in database with the Title and later can use from there but I was looking for something like `select id where title like xyz` so I don't have to include db requests

Comment: (You can even include the name you're looking for in the filter as well, actually.)

Comment: I think that should solve everything you're looking for - and I'm off to bed now. If that doesn't do everything you want, please edit your question with sample code showing what you've tried with the Drive API. (If there isn't anything else, I'd suggest either deleting the question, or editing it and posting your own answer.)

Comment: I can list the spread sheets but the only one which shared with my email. But the issue is my creation email in credentials in different than the one in Google Services. And Google Drive API can only be connected through Service email and details as mentioned in the question. And the Sheets API can only be connected using Gmail account. That is where the conflict is :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Read the question again, just don't look at the code. you will understand what the actual issue is

Comment: No, I haven't misunderstood. The Drive API works fine with user credentials. I don't know how you'd do it with the old GData API, but with Google.Apis.Drive.v3 it works fine with user credentials. Use the right scopes when you create the UserCredential and you should be able to use the same object for both APIs.

Comment: So did you have a chance to try using `Google.Apis.Drive.v3` yet?

Comment: You need to share Sheets created with the service account with the user accounts that need to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create the sheet with the title you want ahead of time? The code below also returns the spreadsheetId for later use. I'm logging the title and id to a file that I can read through later.

```
try {
    Spreadsheet oBody = new Spreadsheet {
        Properties = new SpreadsheetProperties() {
            Title = sheetTitle,
        },
    };
    SpreadsheetsResource.CreateRequest oRequest = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Create(oBody);
    Spreadsheet oResponse = oRequest.Execute();
    result = oResponse.SpreadsheetId;
} catch (Exception e) {
    result = "Google API: " + e.Message;
}
```

REFERENCE: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create